# Issuing a POST request with a large amount of data fails in VB6

Tags: http, post, vb6, msxml, xmlhttprequest

I have a pretty standard function to post some XML string data to a remote WCF service and extract the result. It works fine, but fails to scale to a "large" amount of data (138KB in this case.)

```
' performs a HTTP POST and returns the resulting message content
Function HttpPost(sUrl As String, sSOAPAction As String, sContent As String) As String
  Dim oHttp As Object
  'Set oHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
  oHttp.open "POST", sUrl, False
  oHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", """http://conducive.com.au/IXpacManagement/" & sSOAPAction & """"
  oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
  oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sContent)
  oHttp.send Str(sContent)

  If oHttp.status = 200 Then
    HttpPost = oHttp.responseText
  Else
    MsgBox "An error (" & LTrim(Str(oHttp.status)) & ") has occurred connecting to the server."
    HttpPost = ""
  End If

  Set oHttp = Nothing

End Function
```

When I use `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` I get `error 7 out of memory`.
When I use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` I get `object doesn't support this property or method`.
In either case sending a small string of under a thousand characters works perfectly.

---

Here's what I get when I try different ways of sending the string:

- Using `oHttp.send(sContent)`: Even small POSTs fail with `Invalid procedure call or argument Runtime error 5`.
- Using `oHttp.send sContent`: Even small POSTs fail with `Invalid procedure call or argument Runtime error 5`.

---

In the end `oHttp.send CStr(sContent)` worked. Thank you all for the suggestions because I was lost.

Comment: Just commenting to bring to your attention the fact that the vb tag is in the process of being cleaned up (see the Community Bulletin). You should be replace it with one of the four specific variants, not least of all to make sure you get the help you're after!

Comment: Try using intermediate byte array: `baBuffer = StrConv(...): .send CVar(baBuffer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking out the Str() around sContent and just using parentheses to pass it by value, e.g.

oHttp.send (sContent)

or failing that at least use CStr() - Str() is supposed to convert numbers to strings.

Comment: There is no reason or need to use parentheses at all. You are creating a second copy of a large String.

Comment: @Bob: `send` method has a quirk and it does not "like" VT_BYREF params, most noticable when calling it late-bound.

Comment: I've *only* seen that when XMLHTTP is late-bound myself. But since this is VB6 and not script or something you really want to early bind anyway. If you don't then you are doomed to creating data copies as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Bob: OP is using it late-bound. Skipping a reference to MSXML v42.0 has some merit in being backwards compatible (like win98 backwards).

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I'm not sure what late-binding gets you if you've hard-coded a version dependent ProgId anyway though. Again, copying and recopying data can add up both in CPU and Working Set size, and slapping those parens on there makes a copy. MSXML 4 is obsolete, everything I've seen recommends either 6 or else 3 if you need downlevel compatibility.

Comment: More importantly though, has any of this actually addressed the original problem or are we off in the weeds?

Comment: CStr() did the trick, I'd love to know why exactly! (although a little knowledge of VB is a dangerous thing...) Thank you all.

Comment: @Coxy: Str is an old BASIC function to get the string representation of a number (the opposite of Val, which gives you the number contained in a string). CStr is the "convert to string" function. See also: Int (truncate a floating-point number) vs CInt (convert to integer).